# How to download the .ogg,.wav and etc, file from browser?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to download some sound files through chrome browser without using any downloader, but chrome will open a player and play the sound file, but I want to download it.
example link:
https://robowhale.com/html5/LetMeGrow/deploy/assets/audio/valve.wav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit `Ctrl`+`S` to save the file to your computer

Comment: "STRG"? CTRL, perhaps?

Comment: sure - my mistake (german language)!